# Debian 11 preseed with LUKS and LVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, debian, preseed

I've been trying to automate a Debian install on bare metal with preseed, but I'm stumbling on not being able to partition the filesystem correctly.

**What I want:**

EFI Boot
Swap
Encrypted FDE with a root partition and a /var partition. Both on ext4

**What I'm getting:**

A partitioning error during install saying:
`this probably happened because there are too many (primary) partitions in the partition table`

**How am I trying**

```
# The disk to partition
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/nvme0n1

# LVM with LUKS
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase string inscure
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again string insecure
d-i partman-crypto/weak_passphrase boolean true
d-i partman-crypto/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-crypto/erase_disks boolean false
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-crypto
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
      root-crypto :: \
              538 538 1075 free \
#                    $primary{ } \
                    $iflabel{ gpt } \
                    $reusemethod{ } \
                    method{ efi } format{ } \
              . \
              256 512 512 ext2 \
#                    $primary{ } \
                    $defaultignore{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } \
                    mountpoint{ /boot } \
              . \
              8192 16384 16386 linux-swap \
                    $lvmok{ } \
                    in_vg { crypt } \
                    lv_name{ swap } \
                    method{ swap } format{ } \
              . \
              16384 16385 32768 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root } \
                    in_vg { crypt } \
#                    $primary{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    mountpoint{ /var } \
              . \
              32768 65536 131072 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root } \
                    in_vg { crypt } \
#                    $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    mountpoint{ / } \
              . \

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Force UEFI booting ('BIOS compatibility' will be lost). Default: false.
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label select gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
```

I'm currently testing with a USB stick. Once I have a functioning preseed I'll move to network PXE.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just changed the mapper name on var and it's all good now. For reference:

```
# The disk to partition
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/nvme0n1

# LVM with LUKS
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase string inscure
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again string insecure
d-i partman-crypto/weak_passphrase boolean true
d-i partman-crypto/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-crypto/erase_disks boolean false
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-crypto
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
      root-crypto :: \
              538 538 1075 free \
                    $primary{ } \
                    $iflabel{ gpt } \
                    $reusemethod{ } \
                    method{ efi } format{ } \
              . \
              256 512 512 ext2 \
                    $primary{ } \
                    $defaultignore{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } \
                    mountpoint{ /boot } \
              . \
              8192 16384 16386 linux-swap \
                    $lvmok{ } \
                    in_vg { crypt } \
                    lv_name{ swap } \
                    method{ swap } format{ } \
              . \
              16384 16385 32768 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } lv_name{ var } \
                    in_vg { crypt } \
                    $primary{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    mountpoint{ /var } \
              . \
              32768 65536 131072 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root } \
                    in_vg { crypt } \
                    $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    mountpoint{ / } \
              . \

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Force UEFI booting ('BIOS compatibility' will be lost). Default: false.
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label select gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
```

Specifically changed to

`$lvmok{ } lv_name{ var }`

from

`$lvmok{ } lv_name{ root }`

As / already has root crytpo mapper name